# Arguments ignored when using add_custom_command

Tags: python, cmake, cmakelists-options

I am USing cmake 3.14, and part of the script it's calling another python script and giving it the build path as an argument but the python doesn't receive this argument

```
set(arg ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})    
add_custom_command(TARGET res POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${PYTHON_TEST}  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../script.py ${arg}
  DEPENDS ${arg}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
  COMMENT "Generating results"
             )
```

python log :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
BuildPath = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

of course the python script is running ok if called from CMD .. when i looked on the cmake documentation it says it's ignoring the arguments indeed but i didn't understand what's to be done to pass arguments?

[image]

Comment: What's stored in `PYTHON_TEST`? What does the `message("COMMAND ${PYTHON_TEST}  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../script.py ${arg}")` command print, if inserted directly befor the `add_custom_command`? What's the command `cmake --build ... --verbose` prints?

Comment: Note also, that TARGET flow of the `add_custom_command` doesn't support DEPENDS keyword. You won't find that keyword in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) for that command flow.

Comment: @fabian PYTHON_TEST is python.exe .... and this command prints (pathToPython/python.exe PathToScript/script.py arg) exactly as i want

Comment: @Tsyvarev
actually it supports DEPENDS in this [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/add_custom_command.html)

Comment: @mr.Arrow: No, it doesn't. You use "Build Events" subtype of the command. If you look into the command signature for that subtype, you won't find DEPENDS in it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev i got it, but even after removing `DEPENDS` it still ignore the argument to python ... it doesn't ignore it when i use `execute_process` with the same exact command

Comment: I didn't say that removing DEPENDS will solve your problem. I just noted, that passing that parameter is not useful, as it doesn't mean what you expect from it.

Comment: As for your problem, it is definitely about the COMMAND which you specify. CMake just executes this command when it is needed (when `res` library or executable is built). You could check that if you run your build tool in the verbose mode. (If you build with `make`, then pass additional `VERBOSE=1` parameter to it). It could be that `python.exe` behaves in a specific way when run in your build environment. Since you don't show your python script and the complete `CMakeLists.txt`, we could only *speculate* what is going on. But only you is able to **debug** the issue.